# Can anyone help resolve my polynomial regression model with feature scaling and transformations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, error-handling

The error I got is:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (15,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 15 (dim 0)
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


dataset = pd.read_csv('music.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_poly, y_train)

print(y_train.inverse_transform((regressor.predict([[33,0]]))))
```

This is the full error:

```
print(y_test.inverse_transform((regressor.predict([[33,0]]))))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'inverse_transform'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You report two different errors; please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Could you show a sample of data, so we can see why there is a matrix/vector size mismatch ? and explain what you are trying to do in the last line of code ?

Answer (score 0):

`y_train` is a numpy array, but you are treating it as a fitted encoder.

`y_train.inverse_transform((regressor.predict([[33,0]])))` is your problem. It should be `le.inverse_transform(regressor.predict([[33,0]]))`.

Comment: You mean `le.inverse_transform(y_train)`, right? If yes, please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited to include specifics. I think he is trying to back-transform the output from `regressor.predict([[33,0]])`.

Comment: So I was trying to reverse the feature scaling, thank you so much for the answers!

Comment: ppoint I tried le.inverse_transform(regressor.predict([[33,0]])). However, I am getting the same error

Comment: @YuvvanTalreja which error? Your question is very confusing. You said this is the full error:

```print(y_test.inverse_transform((regressor.predict([[33,0]]))))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'inverse_transform'

Process finished with exit code 1```, however you mention this error at the start of the question: ```ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (15,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 15 (dim 0)```

Which line of code creates which error?

Comment: @ppoint Im very sorry, My error is: 

`print(y_test.inverse_transform((regressor.predict([[33,0]])))) AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'inverse_transform'  
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (15,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 15 (dim 0)
Process finished with exit code 1`